# How can I capture current or active locale in DSpace XMLUI?

Tags: xslt-1.0, dspace

I have this setting in `dspace.cfg` `webui.supported.locales = en, fr, zh`. I wonder why I can't get the active or current locale if I use:

```
    <xsl:value-of
        select="/dri:document/dri:meta/dri:pageMeta/dri:metadata[@element='page'][@qualifier='currentLocale']"/>
```

in my `item-view.xsl`?

Viewing the page eg `http://localhost:8080/DRI/handle/123456789/10476?locale-attribute=fr`, it is obviously there in:

```
<metadata element="page" qualifier="currentLocale">fr</metadata>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, declaring this in a variable in the `global-variables.xsl` eg

```
<xsl:variable name="active-locale" select="/dri:document/dri:meta/dri:pageMeta/dri:metadata[@element='page'][@qualifier='currentLocale']"/>
```

solved my issue.

I can now capture the current/active locale. I still don't know why it won't work if I just use and declare the variable in `item-view.xsl`.

Comment: The `item-view.xsl` page is at a different "context" than the `global-variables.xsl`. The `item-view.xsl` only has access to information that is within the METS file containing all item-level information.  

Since you are asking for something from the DRI document, it is unaccessible from within `item-view.xsl`, but it is accessible from XSL files which have access to the full DRI document.  

This explains why the same variable works in `global-variables.xsl` but not in `item-view.xsl`