# How to move community or collection logo in DSpace xmlui?

Tags: dspace

I would like to move the community or collection logo from its current position which is under the **Search within this community/collection:** form. I would like to put the logo above the `<div id="aspect_artifactbrowser_CollectionViewer_div_collection-home" class="ds-static-div primary repository collection">` just below the community/collection name **OR** to the right of `<div id="aspect_artifactbrowser_CollectionViewer_div_collection-search-browse" class="ds-static-div secondary search-browse">`. I don't know which template to use or how to override it.

I tried this template:

```
<xsl:template match="dri:div[@id='aspect.artifactbrowser.CollectionViewer.div.collection-search-browse']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='LOGO']"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The template match above removed the `Browse by` buttons and the search form.

Answer (score 1):

Your template removes all behaviour that would normally happen for `dri:div[@id='aspect.artifactbrowser.CollectionViewer.div.collection-search-browse']` rather than adding additional bits to it.

To add the logo, you will need to

- find the template that would normally be called for that `dri:div` (which depends on your theme - are you using Mirage 2?),
- copy the contents of that template into your template
- add additional stuff to your template that pulls in the logo.

There is another issue with your approach: You're mixing `mets` and `dri` in your template, same issue as in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042118/how-can-i-capture-current-or-active-locale-in-dspace-xmlui) (see response by Tim Donohue). To access the mets content from within the dri context, you need to load the collection's/community's mets file via a `document()` call, see eg [here](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/common.xsl#L273) in Mirage 2.

Comment: Andrea, thanks for pointing that out. Anyways, I end up using jquery to manipulate the position of the logo. I've tried editing `collection-view.xsl` and `community-view.xsl` where the logo was being pulled but I can't seem to position it to where I want.